# Install nginx on EBS?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

If I launch an instance with EBS storage, how do I install nginx on the EBS volume rather than on the instance?

Does anyone have any tips or a blog post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EBS Volume is not different than your server's root drive if it is the only drive on your server. Everything you install on root drive is on EBS volume. You don't need to worry about the nginx installation if you're installing using EBS root volume. Just install nginx and configure server blocks( Virtual hosts) in nginx config and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks, so if I just log in and cd ~ then sudo apt-get install nginx it will be installed on ebs volume? Is there a way to check this?

Comment: Yes. It will install nginx on root drive. Basically there is no difference between EBS root volume and root volume. check sudo service nginx status should show status of nginx service as active.